# Using GroovyPagesTemplateEngine without a request?

Tags: grails, groovy, template-engine, gsp

I'm trying to evaluate a GSP file without a real http request. I'm trying this:

```
String compileGsp(File input) {
        def text = ''
        try{
            text = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(input).make().toString()
        }
        catch( Exception e ){
            StackTraceUtils.sanitize(e).printStackTrace()
        }

        return text
    }
```

but this throws an exception and yields this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
>   you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.

How can I evaluate GSPs without a request? If I use `SimpleTemplateEngine`, I get some functionality, but I lose all of the taglibs, which include request-void tags like `<g:each>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can mock the web request. This [posting](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/12/27/request-mocking-to-use-groovypagestemplateengine-in-backend-threads/) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I googled and just couldn't find this. I even tried setting up the Mock*Request and Mock*Response. I guess this post will SEO better for future querying. :P