# Render Grails template from external source

Tags: grails

We have a gsp that's stored on S3 to allow realtime updates.  The file has to remain on S3.  I'm retrieving the file and using the Grails templating engine to render it.  However, when calling this code from a Quartz job I get the 'request not attached' error because a Job is not executed within a request context.

I was reading that I should use PageRenderer, which is included in Grails 2.x+.  However, PageRenderer only seems to support reading a template from a relative path (i.e. it expects you to have it locally).  Can someone educate me on a way to render a template using PageRenderer not from a file, but from a String? I've also already tried using a url as the template path, but no luck there.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer to this is fairly trivial, although it required a fair amount of research on my part.  If your using groovyPagesTemplateEngine outside of a request context (i.e. jobs) than you have to mock the request context within the method your calling `template.make()`.  You use to have to write some code and include Spring dependencies to make this happen but now Grails has a nifty little utility that you can use.  Just include `GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest()` before you make your template call and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [at this thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Render-a-GSP-template-or-view-from-a-DB-or-other-datastore-td4638971.html#a4638976) it seems that you can transform a String in a template using `groovyPagesTemplateEngine`. Example:

```
// compile the gsp
def compiledContent = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(content, 'SomeUniqueIdForTheContentBeingRendered')

// render the gsp
def sw = new StringWriter()
compiledContent?.make(args)?.writeTo(sw)
String renderedContent = sw.toString()
```

Comment: This won't work from a job because it doesn't have a bound request. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748704/using-groovypagestemplateengine-without-a-request for that discussion. There was a plugin for this, but it was replaced with PageRenderer: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.4/api/grails/gsp/PageRenderer.html. However, PageRenderer only accepts a path to a template file rather than a template in String form.

Comment: To be fair, this is what I am doing in other areas, but when I called this code from a Quartz job I ran into issues.  That's the rabbit hole I'm in right now.

Comment: Just see your comments right now. If I'm not mistaken there's another topic on the user list that says what you discovered: you need to mock a request.